# Glossary does not appear, only appear acronyms list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

sorry but need some help. Im trying to do a glossary and an acronyms list separate for my thesis, but when i compile, the result is only the list for the acronyms, the glossary terms are ignored. For this Im using a separate file with the glossary an acronyms terms, the form is this:

```
\newglossaryentry{prevalencia}{name={prevalencia}, description={En epidemilogía, proporción de personas que sufren una enfermedad con respecto al total de la
población en estudio}   }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newacronym{MEF}{MEF}{M\'etodo de los elementos finitos}

\newacronym{SM}{SM}{M\'etodos sin malla}

\newacronym{FF}{FF}{Formulaci\'on fuerte}

\newacronym{FD}{FD}{Formulaci\'on d\'ebil}

\newacronym{INTE}{INTE}{``inestabilidad a la tensi\'on"}

\newacronym{CBN}{CBN}{Condiciones de borde tipo Neumman}

\newacronym{MCPF}{MCPF}{M\'inimos cuadrados ponderados fijos}

\newacronym{FHFD}{FHFD}{Formulaciones h\'ibridas fuerte d\'ebil}

\newacronym{maxent}{maxent}{M\'axima entrop\'ia}
```

And in the main.tex I use the next structure,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}     
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                            
\usepackage{fullpage}                           
\usepackage{subfigure}                          
\usepackage{color}                              
\usepackage{colortbl}                           
\usepackage{booktabs}                           
\usepackage{fancybox}                           
\usepackage{graphics}                           
\usepackage{amssymb}                            
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}                 
\usepackage{amsfonts}                           
\usepackage{latexsym}                           
\usepackage{cancel}                             
\usepackage{hyperref}                            
\usepackage{verbatim}                           
\usepackage{ntheorem}                           
\usepackage[centerlast,small,bf]{caption}       
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[acronym, nonumberlist, shortcuts, xindy={ language=spanish-traditional }, toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\include{acronyms}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glosario}
\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Acrónimos}

\begin{document}

   \renewcommand\listfigurename{Índice de Figuras}
   \renewcommand\listtablename{Lista de Tablas}
   \renewcommand\bibname{Bibliografía}
   \renewcommand\indexname{Índice Alfabético}
   \renewcommand\figurename{Figura}
   \renewcommand\tablename{Tabla}
   \renewcommand\partname{Parte}
   \renewcommand\chaptername{Capítulo}
   \renewcommand\appendixname{Apéndice}
   \renewcommand\contentsname{Índice}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \include{Portada/Portada}

  \chapter*{Resumen.}

   En general los métodos numéricos requieren de la discretización del dominio físico, lo cual significa 
   que este debe ser representado por un número finito de puntos que      normalmente son denominados nodos. En los 
   métodos tradicionales, como es el  \gls{MEF} se requiere además conocer la conectividad ...


\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\printglossary[title={Glosario}]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype , title={Acr\'onimos}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glosario}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acrónimos}

\mainmatter             % Activa Números de página tipo arábigos.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\include{Chapter_1/Chapter_1}

\end{document}
```

Sorry, is my first time asking in the forum, always i read only, but in this case, i dont find the solution alone with the information in internet. I proved many things but all failed, and never recognized newglossaryentry, only take newacronym.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you [edit] your example to remove the packages that the example doesn't need?

Answer (score 1):

I removed all the unnessesary packages (you call `graphix` 3 times). Also, you do not call any glossary, so I added a call `\gls{prevalencia}`. xindy gave me problems, so I removed it, and it  produced the glossary and the acronym list.

here's my somewhat more compact actually working example

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[es-noshorthands,spanish]{babel}     
\selectlanguage{spanish}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[acronym, nonumberlist, shortcuts, toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{prevalencia}{
    name={prevalencia}, 
    description={En epidemilogía, proporción de personas que sufren una enfermedad con respecto al total de la población en estudio}   }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newacronym{MEF}{MEF}{M\'etodo de los elementos finitos}

\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glosario}
\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Acrónimos}

\begin{document}

   \renewcommand\listfigurename{Índice de Figuras}
   \renewcommand\listtablename{Lista de Tablas}
   \renewcommand\bibname{Bibliografía}
   \renewcommand\indexname{Índice Alfabético}
   \renewcommand\figurename{Figura}
   \renewcommand\tablename{Tabla}
   \renewcommand\partname{Parte}
   \renewcommand\chaptername{Capítulo}
   \renewcommand\appendixname{Apéndice}
   \renewcommand\contentsname{Índice}


  \chapter*{Resumen.}

   En general los métodos numéricos requieren de la discretización del dominio físico, lo cual significa 
   que este debe ser representado por un número finito de puntos que      normalmente son denominados nodos. En los 
   métodos tradicionales, como es el  \gls{MEF} se requiere además conocer la conectividad ... \gls{prevalencia}


\printglossary[title={Glosario}]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype , title={Acr\'onimos}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glosario}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acrónimos}


\end{document}
```